# Spring boot - How to catch exception when initalising beans which cannot be catched in Main class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I have a simple Spring Boot application which needs to initialize a bean with @Bean annotation inside a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public DataSource sourceDataSource() throws Exception {
        // Some code to connect to database which can throw a exception (e.g: Hibernate) and it cannot be catched in Main class.
    }
}
```

And a SpringBoot Main class to start the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ApplicationMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(ApplicationMain.class, args);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Cannot catch the exception from @Bean here
            log.error("Error application.", ex);
            System.exit(ExitCode.FAILURE.getExitCode());
        }
    }        
}
```

**What is the way to make Spring Boot can just log the error message from sourceDataSource() and it can still run web application and show this error message via a controller (e.g: http://localhost:8080/test/error which returns error, e.g: 'Cannot connect to DataSource because JDBC URL is not valid').**

Comment: `log.error("Error in application: " + ex.getMessage());`

Comment: @diginoise at least tell where to put the command, I think you misunderstood the problem, I know how to get the error message in catch() of the main method.